# User Pool Error: Please enter a valid client id, client secret, or enabled scopes

Tags: android, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to add Google Sign In to my Android app but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do it.

All I want is to when the user signs in with Google, I want them to show up in my Users and Groups. I already can add a user via email sign in, but I can't figure out how to do this with Social Providers.

I copied my app's Client Id (looks like this: xxx-xxx.apps.googleusercontent.com), and Client Secret, which I got from the
Google Developer Console, credentials, OAuth web client, and I am getting this error.

Error: Please enter a valid client id, client secret, or enabled scopes.

Do I need to enter an Authorize Scope? Where do I find this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I guess if I enter in Authorize Scope:

profile email openid

it works. Not sure what other info I can enter in there, but for now this works.